# Dynamic soql : Unexpected token '{'

Tags: dynamic-soql

```
Set<Id> sId = new Set<Id>{};
sId.add('a0df000000063A9AAI');
sId.add('a0df00000006P2cAAE');
String squery = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM Engagement__c  WHERE Id IN:'+sId;
List<Engagement__c> lst = database.query(squery);   
System.debug('----list size:'+lst.size());
```

Im getting the following error

System.QueryException: unexpected token: '{'

Please helppppp! thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Syntax is wrong.

Either use this way :-

```
Set<Id> sId = new Set<Id>();
```

OR

```
Set<Id> sId = new Set<Id>{'a0df000000063A9AAI','a0df00000006P2cAAE'};

// no need to use '+sid;
String squery = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM Engagement__c  WHERE Id IN:sId';

// else is correct
List<Engagement__c> lst = database.query(squery);   
System.debug('----list size:'+lst.size());
```

**Why it cannot be +sId?**

Using this approach will lead to wrong `SOQL` syntax. For ex:

Query String will become:

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Engagement__c  WHERE Id IN:{a0df000000063A9AAI,a0df00000006P2cAAE}
```

which is a wrong syntax for SOQL query.

Comment: It worked. thanks.  Since sId is variable, so I was using as +sId. Why it cannot be +sId?

Comment: Have a look at here http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_soql.htm

Comment: @BruceLee updated answer for `'+sid`.

Comment: One is string concatenation, the other is parameter binding.

Answer (score 4):

Your set variable should declare like,

```
Set<Id> sId = new Set<Id>();
```

Also when you are using Dynamin SOQL there some considerations. You can put a `List` or `Set` variable inside the query, but not like string append as you are currently doing. Alter your query into

```
String squery = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM Engagement__c  WHERE Id IN:sId';
```

Make sure that the variable `sId` is in the scope of where the `Database.query()` is performed. You can get an idea about Dynamic query from [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_soql.htm).